# Accessing AWS SSM Parameters in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssm

I'm trying to get the ssm parameter inside my nodejs project, is IAM credentials I and wrote a test in my elastic beanstalk instance and works. The problem is inside the project. Any ideas why?

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

var ssm = new AWS.SSM();

var options = {
  Name: '/test/test', /* required */
  WithDecryption: false
};
var parameterPromise =  ssm.getParameter(options).promise();

parameterPromise.then(function(data, err) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: what's the output of the above sample code?

Comment: In the /home of instance return the correct  parameter value, inside of nodejs project the promise is never resolved or rejected

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by inside of the nodejs project? Does the CLI succeed but your node code fails? Are you providing sufficient credentials for your application? Can you share the IAM role/policy you are using for the application?

Comment: Yes the CLI works fine, node is a web application with nestjs.

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right region for SSM? Does Elastic Beanstalk have a role with a policy that gives it permission to read from SSM?

Comment: yep, the region is correct, the policy is correct too, because the CLI works..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I discovered, the same of this https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1107

need to pass the region in the SSM constructor

```
var ssm = new AWS.SSM({region: 'us-east-1'});
```

seems to be a bug

tks

Comment: It's not a bug when you deploy some service in AWS it has some region. Also, parameter store variables also created based on region. So you need to mention the region here. Else use https://www.serverless.com/ where you can handle it better.